# Is it possible for SF Community(Identity provider) log in User to all domains assigned to community?

Tags: community, single-sign-on, login, issue

SF Community is Identity provider.
Community_A has 2 domains assigned: domain_1 and domain_2.

Issue: User from Site_X goes to domain_1 and logs in. Result user logs in Site_X and to  Community_A(domain_1). But if user goes to domain_2 he need to log in 2nd time.

Is it possible to configure or to do smth for Community_A for user - while he logs in to domain_1 automatically logs him in to domain_2?

Is there another option? Workarounds?